# Access.log в Apache

Tags: apache

Кто подскажет, что означают последние две цифры в access.log файле в Apache?

```
77.120.254.194 - - [28/Jul/2016:17:25:47 +0300] "POST /tro/ws/kltro HTTP/1.1" 500 283
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В формате по умолчанию это **код HTTP-статуса ответа** и **объём ответа (без заголовков)**.

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
```

[См. документацию к Apache.](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#accesslog)

Comment: Спасибо! Хочу еще спросить, может быть подскажете, 500 - это Internal server error, почему в error.log ничего не пишется? а только в access.log?

Comment: @Lucky_girl скорее всего, потому что не Apache решил, что будет 500, а то, у чего он спрашивает. И сам Apache о проблеме ничего сказать не может. Это мог сказать PHP-интерпретатор, к примеру. Подробнее: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20511956/2076787

Comment: Спасибо большое! То-есть, на самом сервере может и не быть этой ошибки, а, к примеру, клиент может решить, что это 500 ERROR?